# Can't upload Android Kotlin Project to Fabric Beta with gradle

Tags: android, kotlin, crashlytics

I created a project with Android Studio Preview 3.0 (Canary 2) to start Kotlin development. I used the Android Studio Fabric Plugin to setup Fabric for my project.

But when I want to upload a beta version of my app to Fabric Beta (Crashlytics) with the following command

```
./gradlew crashlyticsUploadDistributionDebug
```

I receive the following error:

> Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use
>   'implementation' instead. Configuration 'testCompile' in project
>   ':app' is deprecated. Use 'testImplementation' instead. The
>   Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to
>   be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use
>   registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection) registerResGeneratingTask is
>   deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
>   :app:crashlyticsUploadDistributionDebug FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:crashlyticsUploadDistributionDebug'.
>
>   > Not valid.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1s 1 actionable task: 1 executed, 0 avoided (0%)

I do not have any idea, what "Not valid" means.

This is my root `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {

    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-4'

    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'org.ajoberstar:grgit:1.9.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.22.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

ext {
    supportLibVersion = "25.3.1"
    buildVersion = "25.0.3"
    daggerVersion = "2.9"
    rxJavaVersion = "2.1.0"
    rxAndroidVersion = "2.0.1"

    countGitCommits = { ->
        git = Grgit.open()
        def commitCount = git.log(includes: ['HEAD']).size()
        println("INFO: Number of commits $commitCount")
        return commitCount
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And this is the app `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "$buildVersion"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kotlin.sample"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        def numberOfCommits = countGitCommits()
        versionCode 1000 + numberOfCommits
        versionName "0.1.$numberOfCommits"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'   
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/API_ADK.jar')
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$supportLibVersion"
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.0.3'
    compile "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rxAndroidVersion"
    compile "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rxJavaVersion"
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.1'
    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion"
    // Needed for @Generated annotation (missing in Java <= 1.6; therefore, Android)
    compile 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

The `fabric.properties` file with the apiSecret is also placed in the project.

**Edit:**

A manual upload of the APK to Fabric Beta works.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Our command line tools are not compatible with the Alpha version of Gradle 3. We're looking into the changes that have come with the alpha versions, but we test against betas and stable versions of the releases.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer. Then I know, I don't need to dig deeper. :)

Comment: Getting the same issue here; we moved to gradle 3 alpha in order to take advantage of the vast improvements in Android Studio 3.0. I'm encouraged to see they're fixing this, and meanwhile that we can manually upload builds to Fabric.

Comment: I will be super excited when this is working again! <3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just want to point to the comment from Mike Bonnell as it answers this question:

> Our command line tools are not compatible with the Alpha version of Gradle 3. We're looking into the changes that have come with the alpha versions, but we test against betas and stable versions of the releases.

**Edit 2017/08/25**
Tried with Android Studio 3.0 Beta 3 and the corresponding android gradle plugin. The gradle task `crashlyticsUploadDistributionDebug` seems to work again.

Comment: Getting this with alpha3 - Error:Execution failed for task ':Eruditus:crashlyticsUploadDistributionDevDebug'.
> getMainOutputFile is no longer supported.  Use getOutputFileName if you need to determine the file name of the output.

Comment: Where do we log issues for Crashlytics?